# How can I include 2 or more php files without showing the output?

Tags: php

I am using the functions : `ob_start()` and `ob_end_clean()` / `ob_end_flush` to hide the output of my included php scripts. When I use just one include within the ob functions, I get no output but when I use 2 includes I get the output of them both. Example of my code:

`ob_start();
 include('config.php');
 include('test.php');
 ob_end_flush();`

How can I hide my outputs even when I have 2 includes?

Comment: I hope your `config.php` file doesn't output something..

Comment: Basically including means you are running that file. So if you don't want to see the output you should not echo anything

Comment: Depends a little what's inside the files you're including. Is it pure html (then use a different function and put the result in a variable)? Is it some PHP logic? Also, output buffering isn't a good approach - structure your code better.

Comment: @Qirel My config.php file outputs whether the connection is made or not and the test.php has multiple html forms and embedded php for validation.

Comment: Why do you output if the connection is successful? That as shouldn't be needed. And you can `return` one string from the include and put it into a variable.

Comment: The solution here is to create files that can be included without outputting something, not working around the output.

Comment: surely config.php only returns an an array or something, and outputs nothing?

Answer (score 0):

Ive made some minor syntax errors within my php script and seems to be working.